# how to let cg_annotate include a dictionary?

Tags: linux, directory, valgrind

I've tried to use cg_annotate to include a dictionary by use --include flag. However, no matter what I typed after --include=, it always shows the manual (indicating that my path is wrong).

for example, I typed ".util" after --include= but it shows the manual:
[the sceenview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1U89.png)

The official manual says:

-I --include= [default: none]    Adds a directory to the list in which to search for files. Multiple -I/--include options can be given to add multiple directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 'dictionnary' of directories stored somewhere, you always have
to give the list of directories each time you launch cg_annotate.

So, in your case, the mandatory argument cachegrind-out-file is not provided in your command. This causes cg_annotate to stop and show its usage.

You might possibly use kcachegrind (and --tool=callgrind), as kcachegrind has some support for specifying source directories (if ever that is needed, as normally kcachegrind+callgrind will find automatically the source files).

To add some directories in kcachegrind, you can use the menu entry Settings->Configure Kcachegrind and add directories in the Annotations tab.